# Confusion with Implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Forgive me if its a dumb question, I just started reading Mathematical Logic

**Question:-**

Let we have an Implication,

> A ⟹ B

And its Truth Table is

[image]

This Implication is true for **All False values of “A” irrespective the value of B**.

By this we can conclude that **"If not A then B is false/true"** both are true. So we can say **"If not A then B"** because B only has two value **True or False** and here B can be any thing.

By this reasoning **"If A then B"** should be equal to **If not A then B**

But **when we write a mathematical formula and calculate their truth table then both are different**

- **"If A then B"**

  Mathematical Formula :-

  > A ⟹ B

  Truth Table:-

[image]

Here I am taking only one case(i.e. B is True)

- **"If not A then B"**

  Mathematical Formula :-

  > not A ⟹ B

  ```
  A    B             If not A then B

  T    T                    T
  T    F                    T
  F    T                    T
  F    F                    F
  ```

I am missing something or have some conceptual flaws but unable to find, Please help me

Thank You

---

**P.S. :- Sorry in advance because my English is not upto that mark. Edits are welcome :)**

Comment: @amWhy I know that my question is different I guess

Comment: When A is true and B is false you get false in implication. But replacing A by not A does not work in this case: not A is false and B is false we get true.

Comment: @Bhaskar: Remember not A is not always false. So we cannot say "If not A then B" is always true as you seem to say.

Comment: @Shahab I am asking what is wrong with my reasoning. I know "replacing A by not A does not work". I want an Intuitive Explanation not mathematical formula based :)

Comment: Ok...sorry if I misinterpreted. What do you mean when you say, : "By this we can conclude that "If not A then B is false/true" both are true. " What does both mean?

Comment: In any case, it should be clear to you that $A\to B \neq \lnot A \to B$, given your representation of each in a truth table.

Comment: @amWhy I know that and unable to get it intutively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am confused why you would say that $\neg A \rightarrow B$ should be equivalent to $A \rightarrow B$, given that you just argued that the value of $B$ should not matter, rather than the value of $A$!  In fact, when $A$ is true it is no longer the case that the value of $B$ doesn;t matter, and so you immediately get that $\neg A \rightarrow B$ is *not* the same as $A \rightarrow B$.

What would have made a little more sense is if you would have focused on $A \rightarrow \neg B$ instead, because (as you correctly observed) if $A$ is false, then $A \rightarrow B$ has the same truth-value as $A \rightarrow \neg B$ (namely True). However, that still does not mean that they are equivalent, because equivalence means that they should have the same truth-value under *any* conditions (and again, you have only shown them to have the same truth-value under the condition that $A$ is False). And so $A \rightarrow \neg B$ is also not equivalent to $A \rightarrow B$

Finally, if you are trying to change the $A$ into a $\neg A$, because $A \rightarrow B$ is true when $A$ is false ... well, that makes even less logical sense. Here is an example to demonstrate your faulty logic. Take statement $\neg A$.  This statement is true when $A$ is false ... ok, so by your logic we should be able to change the $A$ with a $\neg A$ and get the same statement? No, because changing the $A$ with a $\neg A$ in $\neg A$ gives us $\neg \neg A$, which is equivalent to just $A$ ... which is not at all equivalent to the original $\neg A$.

Don't confuse statements with their truth-values!!

Comment: Please forgive me, I know it's a very stupid question ........


What is the difference between "If not A then B" and putting the value "Not A" in "If A then B".
...........
I know they are different but unable to get it intuitively

Comment: @Bhaskar I am not sure what you mean by 'putting the value of $neg A$ in $A \rightarrow B$' ... you can replace parts of a statement with a different statement, sure, but that usually gives you a statement with different truth-conditions, as I show in my answer. If you mean that you can substitute $\neg A$ for $A$ because $A$ is false ... absolutely not!  Again, it changes the statement. Think about this: I have statement $A$.  Now you tell me $A$ is false .. ok, so I should be able to change the $A$ into $\neg A$?  No, because when $A$ is false, $\neg A$ is True!

Comment: But isn't"A" is false and "not A" are same I mean have same meaning

Comment: @Bhaskar Yes ... but you are confusing the statement with its truth-value. A statement is just that: a statement. And the statement can be true or false. Just because a statement $A$ is false does not mean you can substitute $\neg A$ for $A$ in some other statement. When you do, you change the statement

Comment: Yes you are right I am confusing a statement with its truth value.... But I don't know why I am still not confident that I got the point.... Can please elaborate... Its a request

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of your problem. You wrote, "If not A then B is false/true". Well, you then analyze "If not A then B". But when you wrote "false/true", you really meant "false OR true". But if you write "If not A then B", you're trying to show a much stronger conclusion than is warranted (A AND B is a stronger conclusion than A OR B), because you're going to need B true, period. As a matter of fact, the statement "If A then (true or false)" is always true, because the consequent is always true.

Another part of your problem, I think, is that you're trying to show these other formulas are true *in the context of* the statement "If A then B". But your later truth tables don't reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Near the beginning of your question, you noticed that, because of the truth table, if $A$ is false, then $A\to B$ is true, regardless of whether $B$ is true or false. That is correct, and it could be expressed by saying that $(\neg A)\to(A\to B)$ is always true. But then you seem to have inferred that $(\neg A)\to B$  and also that $(\neg A)\to(\neg B)$ are true, and I'm afraid there's no justification for either of those inferences.

Answer (score 0):

"If A, then B" is clearly not equivalent to "if not A, then B".

However it is equivalent to "not A or B".   You may be thinking of that.

$$\begin{array}{c:c|c|c:c:c}A & B & \neg A & \neg A\vee B& A\to B ~~& \neg A \to B~~\\\hline T&T&F&T~~~~&T~~~~&T~~~~\\T&F&F&F~~\star&F~~\star&T~~~~\\F&T&T&T~~~~&T~~~~&T~~~~\\ F&F&T&T~~~~& T~~~~&F~~ \star\end{array}$$

$A\to B$ is only false when $A$ is true and $B$ is false.   As is $\neg A \vee B$.   They are equivalent

$\neg A\to B$ is false when $A$ is false and $B$ is false. (ie $\neg A$ is true and $B$ is false.)  So clearly that is not equivalent to the others.$$A\to B ~\iff ~ \neg A\vee B$$